# How to make DataGrid column stretch from C# code?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm creating the columns of a WPF `DataGrid` in my C# code. I want one of the columns to stretch to the width of the `DataGrid` automatically. In XAML, I'd set `Width="*"`. How do I do it in code?

**EDIT**
Some of the answers seem to lead me to the right solution, but I feel I need to elaborate a bit more what I'm trying to do:

I'm actually deriving a new class from `DataGrid`. In its constructor, I add four columns like that:

```
this.IsReadOnly = true;
this.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
this.ItemsSource = m_dataSource;

DataGridTextColumn anColumn = new DataGridTextColumn() { Header = "Col1", Binding = new Binding("B1") };
DataGridTextColumn tpColumn = new DataGridTextColumn() { Header = "Col2", Binding = new Binding("B2") };
DataGridTextColumn txColumn = new DataGridTextColumn() { Header = "Col3", Binding = new Binding("B3") };
DataGridTextColumn mdColumn = new DataGridTextColumn() { Header = "Col4", Binding = new Binding("B4") };

this.Columns.Add(anColumn);
this.Columns.Add(tpColumn);
this.Columns.Add(txColumn);
this.Columns.Add(mdColumn);
```

I tried setting the last column's width like *user24601* suggested:

```
mdColumn.Width = new DataGridLength(0.5, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star);
```

But this creates a column that is so wide I can scroll and scroll for a *very* long time... Same problem when I use `0.1` or even smaller values.

I seems to me I'm doing it in the wrong place somehow?

**EDIT 2**
OK, I may have the problem because I'm actually adding this to a `ScrollViewer`. I'll run some further tests first...

**EDIT 3**
Well, things don't work when having the `DataGrid` within a `ScrollViewer`... When I remove the `ScrollViewer`, things work like *user24601* said.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're actually using something called a [DataGridLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridlength.aspx) there.

Try something like this:

```
Grid.ColumnDefinitions[0].Width = new DataGridLength(0.2, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star);
Grid.ColumnDefinitions[1].Width = new DataGridLength(0.8, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star);
```

That will split the remaining space 80% / 20% between these two columns.

Comment: Hm. I've come up with this, too, but this creates the column to be *a lot* wider than my window. I'm elaborating my question a little - maybe things become clearer.

Comment: To be fair, a little correction is needed: What you wrote doesn't work for `DataGridTextColumns`. There, you have to use `dataGrid.Columns[i].Width = new DataGridLength(1, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star)`

Comment: You are correct.  I'll edit my answer.  I got the type right at the first comment just not in the answer itself.

Answer (score 0):

try this

`DataGrid1.Width = double.NaN;`

Comment: This throws an `ArgumentException` saying that `value can not be infinite`.

Comment: This answer is correct for the datagrid width, not for a column's width.